# Download xml generated dynamically

Tags: php, html, xml, download

I need download the XML that I generate dynamically but when I try this, the file has all the HTML code. I new on this but I can't find the way to do that I want.

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])){
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("document")->item(0);
$feed = $xml->createElement("feed");
$asset = $xml->createElement("asset");
$video = $xml->createElement("video");
$aTag = $xml -> createElement("FileName",$_REQUEST['FileName']);    
$bTag = $xml -> createElement("Network",$_REQUEST['Network']);
$feed->appendChild($asset);
$asset->appendChild($bTag);
$feed->appendChild($video);
$video->appendChild($aTag);
$rootTag = $xml->appendChild($feed);
$xml->save("a.xml");
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a.xml"');
exit;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>XML </title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="index.php"> <table width="357" border="0"> 
<tr> <td width="90">FileName:</td> <td width="257"><input name="FileName" type="text" id="FileName" size=30 /></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Network:</td> <td><label> <input name="Network" type="text" id="Network" size=30 /> </label></td> </tr>
<tr> <td height="41" colspan="2"><label></label>
 <div align="center"> <input type="submit" name="Submit"  value="Descargar">
 <label> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Cancelar" /> </label> </div></td> </tr> </table> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: `header();` must be called before any other ouput like : `<!doctype html>`. In your code the headers wont be set. Test it with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Move the `if()` up at first in the file and do an `exit;` after `header('Content-Dispo`.

Comment: replace DOMDocument with SimpleXMLElement

Comment: thanks @JustOnUnderMillions I tried that but now the file is downloaded empty.

Comment: I forget to add readfile("a.xml");  now, works fine. thank you!

Comment: Nice!.................:)